# How can I run a local instance of AdGuard Home on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, systemd, podman, docker-compose

I want to run AdGuard Home on my Ubuntu Server (23.04) and point the router to the server in order to block ads etc. on my network. However, I'm running into all sorts of issues in regards to ports. Specifically, port 53, 67, and 68.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` I've written (however, I use `podman` and not `docker`):

```yml
version: "3.4"
services:
  adguardhome:
    image: "adguard/adguardhome"
    container_name: "adguardhome"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "68:68/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
      - "443:443/udp"
      - "3000:3000/tcp"
      - "853:853/tcp"
      - "853:853/udp"
      - "784:784/udp"
      - "8853:8853/udp"
      - "5443:5443/tcp"
      - "5443:5443/udp"
    volumes:
      - "./work:/opt/adguardhome/work"
      - "./conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf"
```

I ran the command `sudo podman-compose up -d` but it complained about port 53 being bound. So I did the steps below.

What I've tried:

- [Followed the instructions from their official Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/adguard/adguardhome#resolved-daemon) for `systemd-resolved`.

  - Doing `sudo lsof -i :53` shows that `systemd-resolved` did not occupy the port anymore, but `libvirt-dnsmasq` did.
- Edited the configs by running `sudo virsh net-edit default` and adding the line `<dns enable=no />`.

  - `sudo lsof -i :53` does not return anything; nor does `sudo netstat -tuln | grep 53`.
  - Re-ran the command `sudo podman-compose up -d`; it complained about port 67 being bound.
- Running `sudo lsof -i :67` shows that `libvirt-dnsmasq` is still occupying the port.

  - I couldn't find any useful resources online on how to disable it. Since most of the resources were pretty old the info was outdated (many of the files told to edit simply didn't exist etc.), so I just resorted to `sudo kill <pid>`
  - Re-ran the command `sudo podman-compose up -d`; it complained about port 68 being bound. I check using `lsof` and `ps aux | grep <pid>`, and found out that `systemd-networkd` is using it.
- Adding `network_mode: host` to the `docker-compose` file yields the following:

```bash
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.3.1
** excluding:  set()
['podman', 'network', 'exists', 'adguardhome_default']
['podman', 'network', 'create', '--label', 'io.podman.compose.project=adguardhome', '--label', 'com.docker.compose.project=adguardhome', 'adguardhome_default']
['podman', 'network', 'exists', 'adguardhome_default']
podman run --name=adguardhome -d --label io.podman.compose.config-hash=123 --label io.podman.compose.project=adguardhome --label io.podman.compose.version=0.0.1 --label com.docker.compose.project=adguardhome --label com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/home/tester/containers/adguardhome --label com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yml --label com.docker.compose.container-number=1 --label com.docker.compose.service=adguardhome --network host --cap-add NET_ADMIN -v /home/tester/containers/adguardhome/work:/opt/adguardhome/work -v /home/tester/containers/adguardhome/conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf --net adguardhome_default --network-alias adguardhome -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 67:67/udp -p 68:68/udp -p 80:80/tcp -p 443:443/tcp -p 443:443/udp -p 3000:3000/tcp -p 853:853/tcp -p 853:853/udp -p 784:784/udp -p 8853:8853/udp -p 5443:5443/tcp -p 5443:5443/udp --restart unless-stopped adguard/adguardhome
Error: cannot set multiple networks without bridge network mode, selected mode host: invalid argument
exit code: 125
podman start adguardhome
Error: no container with name or ID "adguardhome" found: no such container
exit code: 125
```

I'm at a loss. I really do not know what to do and why things are behaving the way they are; and certainly I cannot disable everything on the system just to get AGH to work.

1. Had `network_mode: host` worked, would there have been any drawbacks for my use-case (besides the container not being accessible from other containers)?
2. I noticed that adding `127.0.0.1:` in front of the ports does not cause any issues - is this a viable solution? Are there any drawbacks to this?

Comment: You are trying to expose a port on your host which is already occupied by a service. You can eIther pick a different port or stop the service.

Comment: @Panki yes. Aren't the various ports for DoH, DoQ etc? Can I then use a different port for these types of DNS?

Comment: You can use any port you want, as long as you set the same ones in the clients trying to access the services.

Comment: @Panki I see. I have a TP-Link AX5400 router, which only allows me to set the IP (without the port) on the DNS - wouldn't this mean that changing the port would not pass DoH through?